# UITableView from plist loaded into NSArray of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

I have been reading a bunch of how to's on this topic, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

If I have a plist like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>brown</string>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>40</real>
        <key>length</key>
        <real>75</real>
        <key>level</key>
        <real>2</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>bear</string>
        <key>note</key>
        <string>ugly, but strong</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>30</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>tan</string>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>20</real>
        <key>length</key>
        <real>30</real>
        <key>level</key>
        <real>4</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>dog</string>
        <key>note</key>
        <string>cute</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>8</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>chestnut</string>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>75</real>
        <key>length</key>
        <real>90</real>
        <key>level</key>
        <real>3</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>horse</string>
        <key>note</key>
        <string>fast</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>22</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>gray</string>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>20</real>
        <key>length</key>
        <real>85</real>
        <key>level</key>
        <real>2</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>shark</string>
        <key>note</key>
        <string>hungry!</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>35</real>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I can load the data and print the whole list like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"testdata" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *foodsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"Did Load - FoodsList = %@", foodsList);
```

But when I go to load it into a UITableView so I could have a list of names, I can't get it working.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[testdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

The NSMutableArray *keyValues = testdata[key]; line fails going between Dictionary and Array types.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Thank you to everyone for responding.  I found I had an error in the numberOfRowsInSection ... It was apparently stopping everything from being executed.  I will detail it in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the text anywhere inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

set cell label text

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello World";
```

Comment: Fixed the error you put in and I put a NSLog statement inside the UITableViewCell section and I don't even see the program get there ... Looking into why right now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way how you structure the data in your plist, or in the way you are trying to read the content of it.

First of all, you define 4 arrays of Dictionaries, which contains 7 keys (color, height, length, level, name, note, width) with respective values.

Thus, for each row (total of 4), you can access the keys/values of it by getting the dictionary of properties:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ...
    NSDictionary* rowProperties = [testdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString* color = [rowProperties objectForKey:@"color"];
    NSNumber* height = [rowProperties objectForKey:@"height"];
    ...
}
```

If you need to access the data from another way, maybe you can change de plist data to adapt it for that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (NSArray *)plist
{
    if (plist == nil)
    {
        // Get the URL of the property list
        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PropertyList" withExtension:@"plist"];

        // Load the contents of the property list in to a NSData object
        NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


        NSPropertyListFormat propertyListFormat;
        NSError *error;

        // Create an immutable property list from the data
        _plist = (NSArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&propertyListFormat error:&error];

        // Check for error
        if (error)
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"[Property List] %@", [error description]);
#endif
            // Return nil if there is one
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return plist;
}

- (id)propertyListKeyAtIndex:(NSInteger)aKeyIndex inDictionaryAtIndex:(NSInteger)aDictionaryIndex
{
    // Load the dictionary
    NSDictionary * __weak dictionary = (NSDictionary *)self.plist[aDictionaryIndex];

    // Load all of the keys
    NSArray * __weak keyArray = [dictionary allKeys];

    // Return with the key
    id key = keyArray[aKeyIndex];

    return key;
}

- (id)valueForPropertyListKey:(NSString *)aKey inDictionaryAtIndex:(NSInteger)aDictionaryIndex
{
    // Load the dictionary
    NSDictionary * __weak dictionary = (NSDictionary *)self.plist[aDictionaryIndex];

    // Get the value of the key from the dictionary
    id object = dictionary[aKey];

    // Return with the value
    return object;
}
```

OR

```
NSString * __weak key = (NSString *)[(NSDictionary *)self.plist[0] allKeys][0];
id value = self.plist[0][key];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which will load the appropriate cell based on the row number in the table view. That row number will be used as the index in the array holding your dictionaries.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSMutableDictionary *rowProperties = self.keyValues[indexPath.row]; // keyValues is an array holding your dictionaries from the plist

    NSString *color = rowProperties[@"color"];

    cell.textLabel.text = color;
    // continue the same process for all of your items in your dictionary

    return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It put in NSLog statements in each function, I only saw two responses out of seven, so that put me on to tracking down why the UITableViewCell wasn't being called.

In the initialization of the number of rows I had the wrong var name for the array which pointed to a Nil value, so in effect I was saying there were zero rows, so there was no need to proceed and further.

In the example below, "testdata" had been replaced with "namedata", which had a NIL value.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger *Count = [@(testdata.count) integerValue];

    return Count;

}
```

I will have to be more careful about checking my work before I bother you all again.

I thank each of you for your help ... I will be studying why you responded the way you did ... Always more to learn ...

Dan